# Angular Material Chips effect without angular material

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm currently working with Angular-material, but I face a situation in another project that obliged me to use something like [angular material chips](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/chips) effect as described in this link.

The main trouble for me is that I want to do this without angular material.
just jquery, angular, html and css.
Thanks in advance for reply to this.

Comment: Try this http://decipherinc.github.io/angular-tags/ . You can create tags input without angular material.If that's what you meant ?

Comment: How about copy pasting the relevant html, css and js for this particular feature from angular-material? Isn't it open source?

Comment: @Rishab777, thanks that is it.

Comment: @TJ, I don't think like this first time, thanks I will try it soon.
It's open source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest like ; (But  i really love verymuch material components)

http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/demos

there is many many options. Sorry writed as answer right now i can not write comments. StackExcahnge does not look me like a man ;)

Comment: Thanks @Mkan, almost same as Rishab777's comment up there.